# Consume directly from ActiveMQ Artemis replica

Tags: activemq-artemis

In a cluster scenario using HA/Data replication feature is there a way for consumers to consume/fetch data from a slave node instead of always reaching out to the master node (master of that particular queue)?

If you think about scalability, having all consumers call a single node responsible to be the master of a specific queue means all traffic goes to a single node.

Kafka allows consumers to fetch data from the closest node if that node contains a replica of the leader, is there something similar on ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. Consumers can only consume from an active broker and slave brokers are not active, they are passive.

If you want to increase scalability you can add additional brokers (or HA broker pairs) to the cluster. That said, I would recommend careful benchmarking to confirm that you actually *need* additional capacity before increasing your cluster size. A single ActiveMQ Artemis broker can handle millions of messages per second depending on the use-case.

As I understand it, Kafka's semantics are quite different from a "traditional" message broker like ActiveMQ Artemis so the comparison isn't particularly apt.